# What is the correct way to implement a custom block with twig template?

Tags: theming, 8, blocks

I know there are tons of posts for this but I think I have a problem with understanding how a custom block with a custom template is meant to work in Drupal 8.

### Problem

#### My aim:

To place a custom block to display social icons. The block needs some logic (generate a url for example).

#### My main problem:

Everything seems to work so far but I do not get the variables passed through the twig-template (url and urlencode). They always contain the default value from the module-file (null).

#### What I have so far:

Files under /modules/custom/wzm_social_icons:

- wzm_social_icons.info.yml
- wzm_social_icons.module
- src/Plugin/Block/WzmSocialIconsBlock.php
- templates/block--wzmsocialicons.html.twig

I installed the module and also placed a custom block with id "socialicons". The block itself is just a placeholder with no special fields.

### Files

**wzm_social_icons.module**

```
function wzm_social_icons_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array('block__wzm_social_icons' =>
    array(
      'variables' => array(
        'url' => null,
        'urlencoded' => null
      ),
      'template' => 'block--wzmsocialicons'
    )
  );
}
```

**WzmSocialIconsBlock.php**

```
class WzmSocialIconsBlock extends BlockBase {
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function build() {
    $oUrl = Url::fromRoute('<current>');
    $sUrl = $oUrl->toString();
    $sUrl = \Drupal::request()->getSchemeAndHttpHost() . $sUrl;
    $sUrlEncoded = urlencode($sUrl);

    return array(
      '#url' => $sUrl,
      '#urlencoded' => $sUrlEncoded
    );
  }
}
```

Nothing special in the twig-template - just the output for {{ url }} and {{ urlencode }}.

I think my main problem is to understand what needs to be declared with which key in the module-file and if the custom-block-id is used somewhere. No clue so far.

Thanks for any help!

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there. In your `WzmSocialIconsBlock.php` return the following:

```
return array(
  '#theme' => 'block_wzm_social_icons',
  '#url' => $sUrl,
  '#urlencoded' => $sUrlEncoded,
);
```

You might also want to simplify your `hook_theme` by letting it autodetect your template by name:

```
return array('block_wzm_social_icons' =>
  array(
    'variables' => array(
      'url' => null,
      'urlencoded' => null
    ),
);
```

And name your template `templates/block-wzm-social-icons.html.twig`.

Comment: Unfortunately not. Neither `'block__wzm_social_icons'` nor `'block__wzmsocialicons'` nor `'block__socialicons'` nor `'block--socialicons'` works for `'#theme'` there. Also purged cache.

Comment: I updated my answer. Indeed, be sure to clear cache.

Comment: Helped - but did _not_ have to change the template's file name - guess because it's declared in theme-file before. Solved - thx!